# I couldnt find option to List<WebElement> when I moused over driver.findElement in selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

According to the tutorial I saw on YouTube which was created in 2021, when the instructor mouseover `.findElement`, the return type was a list of WebElement but when I did the same today (2023) there was no return type.
Here is the video:
https://youtu.be/FtpIv7T6G28?t=624

The original code was this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div\[@class=\\"inventory_list\\"\]/div"));
```

He was able to store the return type into web element like this.

```
List<WebElement> webelements = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div\[@class=\\"inventory_list\\"\]/div"));
```

When I mouse over the `findElement`, I didn't get any return type.

I am having an issue with how to store the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `findElements` method instead of `findElement`, because `findElements` method returns a list of elements.

```
List<Webelement> allelements=driver.findelements(By.xpath(""));
String allEl=allelements.gettext();
```